# Identification of a threaded connector (on a speed sensor)

Tags: sensor, connector, identification, hall-effect, thread

I'm trying to identify the mating connector for this speed sensor. The sensor in itself is a custom CNC job so no datasheet available...

It's got three pins and 5 "grooves". The exterior thread is a tad less than 1/4".

Subsidiary question : I think it is a hall sensor since it has 3 pins and the end is magnetic, any idea how to identify which pin is which?

[image: Connector 1]
[image: Connector 2]

Thanks by advance!

Comment: Not dissimilar to some made by Lemo.

Comment: Looks very Lemo-esque

Comment: I would describe it as a "5 notch shrouded polarized military male connector" if that helps in search engines.

Comment: What's that engraved on the connector barrel? Might be useful.  Also, if you can photo the whole connector side on, some manufacturers have distinctive marking or knurling (such as Lemo's chocolate bloc). Or is that it before it joins to the sensor body?

Comment: @Andyaka  Are there Lemo connectors with a thread?  I'm yet to come across a Lemo with a thread.

Comment: Hi Guys,
Thanks for the answers, will start digging into the LEMO catalog straightaway.
As for any markings, they are proprietary (clearly done in-house) and do not point to any public reference.

Comment: Lemo M, V and W series are have a thread, maybe others too. But the o-ring/gasket doesn't look right.  Lemo usually have an O ring in between two concentric cylinders, where this connector looks like it has a flat gasket at the bottom of a groove and the mating part will have a flat ground end face. The contact bloc doesn't feel quite right either.  Fischer and ODU are in the same market segment as Lemo, worth checking them too. Maybe also some of the less expensive makes.

Comment: Hi Jack,
Eventually, it doesn't seem to be LEMO. Indeed, the M series is the closest I can find but not exactly...
Will take a look at Fischer and ODU. Maybe M8 or M12 too. Haven't had the chance to take a caliper to it but will dos shortly.

Comment: If you can identify the thread (in particular if it is US or metric) that might help too.